# Pygame keydown K_RIGHT not working

Tags: python, pygame

When the keys W and D are pressed at the same time, pygame can't get the event of the right key being pressed, every other key gets detected, but no the Right Key.

Here I tested printing every key that is being pressed down:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode( (600, 480) )

while True:
    events=pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print(event.key)
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(30)
```

And while 119 (W) and 100 (D) are pressed, 275 (Right Key) is no longer printed, but all other keys will still continue to print.

Is this a pygame error? How can it be solved otherwise?

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. Could you please tell us what version of python you are using?

Comment: I use Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are certain combinations of keys that keyboards cannot handle.  This is because of the keyboard, not Pygame, and this issue cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For handling several keys being pressed at once I recommend using:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w]:
     #do something
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
     #do somthing
```